# Service Fabric Networking - Is it possible to have two nodes of different Node types on one VM?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-on-premises

I'm asking this in relations to my previous post.  I've done some reading but haven't seen a clear answer to my comment Diego's answer.

[Service Fabric - How to reserve or protect my hardcoded Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48835919/service-fabric-how-to-reserve-or-protect-my-hardcoded-port/48864535#48864535)

UPDATE: **As I flesh this out i think the question really becomes can you have mulitple nodes on one VM.  Its not really about node types but nodes them selves.**  So the question is:  Can i have a multiple IP'd VM that hosts Service Fabric and then host two nodes of different type types on it?

That way I could solve the above problem in and have a node type for external access and second node type for internal access instead of Hardcoding a port that is out of the range used during cluster set up.

I guess i'll get greedy and ask the follow up question here:

If i can not have multiple IPs is there anything to be concerned about by using a port outside of the range.  Will service Fabric use that Port Number for anything else?

For example I wouldn't want Service Fabric to not think the micro service needs to be managed just like all other micro services just because the port is outside of the range?

For example in my onPrem ClusterConfig.Windows.MultiMachine.json file I currnetly have:

```
"nodes": [
    {
        "nodeName": "vm0",
        "iPAddress": "Server1.DomainName.net",
        "nodeTypeRef": "NodeType0",
        "faultDomain": "fd:/dc1/r0",
        "upgradeDomain": "UD0"
    },
    {
        "nodeName": "vm1",
        "iPAddress": "Server2.DomainName.net",
        "nodeTypeRef": "NodeType0",
        "faultDomain": "fd:/dc1/r1",
        "upgradeDomain": "UD1"
    },
    {
        "nodeName": "vm2",
        "iPAddress": "Server3.DomainName.net",
        "nodeTypeRef": "NodeType0",
        "faultDomain": "fd:/dc1/r2",
        "upgradeDomain": "UD2"
    }
]
"nodeTypes": [
        {
            "name": "NodeType0",
            "clientConnectionEndpointPort": "19000",
            "clusterConnectionEndpointPort": "19001",
            "leaseDriverEndpointPort": "19002",
            "serviceConnectionEndpointPort": "19003",
            "httpGatewayEndpointPort": "19080",
            "reverseProxyEndpointPort": "19081",
            "applicationPorts": {
                "startPort": "20001",
                "endPort": "20100"
            },
            "isPrimary": true
        }
    ],
```

Can i instead do something like this where IP 1 and 4, 2 and 5 and 3 and 6 are on the same VM?  Notice the start and end ports for the two node types are not split to allow for the hard coded WebAPI endpoints.

```
"nodes": [
    {
        "nodeName": "vm0",
        "iPAddress": "IPAddress_1",
        "nodeTypeRef": "NodeType0",
        "faultDomain": "fd:/dc1/r0",
        "upgradeDomain": "UD0"
    },
    {
        "nodeName": "vm1",
        "iPAddress": "IPAddress_2",
        "nodeTypeRef": "NodeType0",
        "faultDomain": "fd:/dc1/r1",
        "upgradeDomain": "UD1"
    },
    {
        "nodeName": "vm2",
        "iPAddress": "IPAddress_3",
        "nodeTypeRef": "NodeType0",
        "faultDomain": "fd:/dc1/r2",
        "upgradeDomain": "UD2"
    }
]


"nodes": [
    {
        "nodeName": "vm3",
        "iPAddress": "IPAddress_4",
        "nodeTypeRef": "NodeType1",
        "faultDomain": "fd:/dc1/r0",
        "upgradeDomain": "UD0"
    },
    {
        "nodeName": "vm4",
        "iPAddress": "IPAddress_5",
        "nodeTypeRef": "NodeType1",
        "faultDomain": "fd:/dc1/r1",
        "upgradeDomain": "UD1"
    },
    {
        "nodeName": "vm5",
        "iPAddress": "IPAddress_6",
        "nodeTypeRef": "NodeType1",
        "faultDomain": "fd:/dc1/r2",
        "upgradeDomain": "UD2"
    }
] 
"nodeTypes": [
        {
            "name": "NodeType0",
            "clientConnectionEndpointPort": "19000",
            "clusterConnectionEndpointPort": "19001",
            "leaseDriverEndpointPort": "19002",
            "serviceConnectionEndpointPort": "19003",
            "httpGatewayEndpointPort": "19080",
            "reverseProxyEndpointPort": "19081",
            "applicationPorts": {
                "startPort": "20001",
                "endPort": "20500"
            },
            "isPrimary": true
        }
"name": "NodeType1",
            "clientConnectionEndpointPort": "19000",
            "clusterConnectionEndpointPort": "19001",
            "leaseDriverEndpointPort": "19002",
            "serviceConnectionEndpointPort": "19003",
            "httpGatewayEndpointPort": "19080",
            "reverseProxyEndpointPort": "19081",
            "applicationPorts": {
                "startPort": "20501",
                "endPort": "21000"
            },
    ],
```

Thanks in advance, 
Greg

Comment: @chacko-MSFT any thoughts on this one?  Please take a look at my comment to Diego

Comment: @Mike Morton I see you are monitoring these guys, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the Standalone Deployment Preparation steps you can not have two nodes on one VM.

"In a production environment however, Service Fabric supports only one node per physical or virtual machine."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-standalone-deployment-preparation#determine-the-initial-cluster-size

Answer (score 2):

**Yes and No.**

When you install SF Cluster on Development Machine, it simulates a 5 node cluster in the same machine, by default you can't do it when you provision from azure portal.
Service Fabric is nothing more than windows services running on top of Virtual Machines.

The question here should be:

> If I have two node types in the same machine, would it solve my port
>   conflict problem?

The answer is no, because they both would be competing for the ports the same way as when you try to load a single service binded to port 80 on all nodes in your local development machine.

As I suggested on the other question, if creating node types is not an option, you should use the hard-coded ports outside the list of the application ports.

For example:
- ServiceA is an API that exposes operations on port 80
- ServiceB is a background worker service that uses a random port(taken from application ports range)

Designing your service this way, you won't have issues with ports.

The other option would be let all services use random ports and use the reverse proxy to contact them, check it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy).

Comment: Hmmm, I have many servers that have multiple IP addresses that share the same port (For Example 443) for multiple sites hosted on one box.  As long as the IP Port combination is unique you can host and have multiple sites live on the same port.  That should resolve your concerns about competition for a port?  I know you can easily do this IIS and websites, the question is can you do this on Service Fabric with Node Types?

Comment: AFAIK, in SF is not possible to define which Network\IP you should bind to each service, the only way I am aware of is to hard code the IPs in your listeners once you start the service, like you would do on IIS, but is not a flexible solution.

Answer (score 0):

In general you keep a public facing service (I.e Asp.net core api) to be consumed by external clients(anyone who is accessing from outside the sf cluster). You use this api service to invoke other micro services hosted in the same cluster. You can use remoting as communication stack within the cluster. This way you don’t have to worry about the ports in cluster.

Only port which is needed is 80 or some other for external client on which api service is listening. This is the preferred way as per the documentation as well.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what we are doing, @diego recommended using different node types to host the WebAPI endpoint so that we do not have Port conflicts.  My follow up question is can we host two node types on one VM using a multi IP'd NIC?

Comment: I believe that will be quite challanging, I haven't tried that yet on azure.